# Semantic UI toast notification overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I have written the below markup to create toast notifications and I show the div whenever there is a notification.

The issue I am facing is the toast notifications are overlapping on each other but I want them to be one under another so that if the first notification appears it should be on the top, and at the same time if the second notification appears it should be after or below the first notification.

```
<div class="ui positive green message hidden">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
--------------------------------
** The first notification **
--------------------------------

---------------------------------
** The second notification **
--------------------------------
```

They should never overlap on each other.

Comment: what if you give each `div` with a class of `ui` a `margin-bottom: 40px;`

Comment: I did tried it but the position is absolute so it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok. so, what you are doing is giving each notification a position of absolute. This causes each notification to stack one on top the other. One possible easy solution is to remove the `position: absolute;` from this div, `<div class="ui positive green message hidden">` and create a container for all of your notifications. Finally, give the container div (`notification-container`) a position of absolute.

```css
.notification-container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class=notification-container>

  <div class="ui positive green message hidden">
    <i class="close icon">icon</i>
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <p>The first notification</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="ui positive green message hidden">
    <i class="close icon">icon</i>
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <p>The second notification</p>
  </div>

</div>
```